# send email using redis and php

Tags: php, redis

hey guys i am new to redis with php. I am currently working with symfony. I have written a simple form which accept data and send the mail. here is my controller

```
namespace Ens\NewBundle\Controller;
use Ens\NewBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

require '/var/www/predis/autoload.php';
        \Predis\Autoloader::register();



require_once('Services/Notification.php');

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
```

function to be performed on starting.

```
 public function indexAction()
    {
            $x=array('to'=>'ucerturohit@gmail.com','name'=>'Rohitashv singhal');

$client = new \Predis\Client();

//$client->lpush('email','ucerturohit@gmail.com');


//$u=$client->blpop('emailnew',0);

//var_dump($u);

        $product=new Product();
        $product->setName('rohit');
        $product->setPass('rohit');

        $form=$this->createFormBuilder($product)
        ->add('name','text')
        ->add('pass','password')
        ->getForm();
    $z=notification_on_signup($x);

        if($z)
               $name='success';
        else
               $name='failed';

    return $this->render('EnsNewBundle:Email:ind.html.twig',
    array('form'=>$form->createView(),'name'=>'rohit'));


}
```

}

here notification_on_signup function is defined in another function which is sending mail. when i am clicking on submit button then i am calling the same function again. what I want is that when I submit the form then the form should come first and the email function `notification_on_signup` should run in the background. how should i use the redis to send the function in background. please help

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, I think this doesn't have anything to do with redis. Instead you have to use a Job Server such as [gearman](http://gearman.org/)